# XAMPP v3.2.2 with PHP 7.1 error The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, visual-studio-code, localhost

When trying to login to PhpMyAdmin, I'm getting the error:

> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

I'm using XAMPP v3.2.2 and PHP v7.2.1 on a Win7 machine.

The error happened after setting up VS CODE to debug PHP..

I've tried all solutions in similar posts, but none of them seem to work.

The entries below in my php.ini file(entries that apparently are supposed to fix the problem) have been changed to :

> extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"   (set full path to ext folder)
>
> extension=mbstring   (uncommented )
>
> extension=mysqli    (uncommented )

I'm still not able to login to phpmyadmin even after changing the entries.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

It may be the case that the extension references in your **php.ini** file should look like:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

The extension names need to match what is listed in the ext directory.

Comment: I tried that too, but apparently it makes no difference. Actually, above those lines in php.ini there's a commented message that says: ; Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and
; 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
; move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.

Comment: This likely goes without saying, but I assume you're restarting your service after the changes.

Comment: Actually I did not restart apache after making the changes to php.ini (after setting up vs code to debug). I only shutdown my computer.. when turned on computer again, the problem showed up

Comment: That peculiar.  This is the comment in my ini file (sorry very difficult to read this way):

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll

Comment: ^^^ That's not clear... Do you mean use "extension = mbstring.dll" instead of "mbstring"?

Comment: Yes.  The lack of line breaks makes this very difficult to read.  Sorry.  The short of the comment in my ini file says that the extension syntax should be extension=modulename.extension.  It then gave an example on Windows that might look like extension=mysql.dll.

Comment: What happens if you use PHP's built-in web server?  I don't have any experience using XAMPP.

Comment: Me neither... i'm not sure what built-in server you are talking about

Comment: PHP has a built-in web server that can be used for development purposes.  http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: I think that that does not give me access to phpMyAdmin... I need to access phpMyAdmin so I can access my databases

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to enable `extension=exif` after `extension=mbstring`?

EXIF has a dependency on mbstring and both these extensions enabled solves the problem of PhpMyAdmin.